# HTTP POST issue without filename

Tags: php, apache

I have a form that uses the POST method to send data. The POST destination is configured as "http://www.example.com/form". However, the actual POST file is "http://www.example.com/form/index.php".

Because the action does not include the file name (index.php), the POST variables are not making it to the page. (This said, GET requests seem to work fine.)

Short of changing the action and/or method, is there any fix for this? Can I implement a mod_rewrite rule to pass the POST values along to the page?

Comment: Have you tried using a firefox plugin such as tamper data or httpfox to the look at the request? Have you just tried var_dump($_POST), even removing the action on the form completely if the form is on the index.php page

Comment: I tried var_dump($_POST) to no avail -- it came back empty. Also, I have the form on a page other than the POST destination index.php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce this with

```
<form action="/test/" method="POST">
```

But I was able to reproduce it with

```
<form action="/test" method="POST">
```

In the second case my Apache send as Moved-Permanently redirect to `/test/` and the POST variables are lost.

This redirect is done by [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html).
If you disable `mod_dir` links to a directory without a trailing slash a simply not working any more.

The only advice I can give you is to fix the form's action.

Comment: Looking closer to the code, your scenario 2 is actually what I'm seeing on my end, not scenario 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have access to the form, but I'm going to let the team that manages it know that there's nothing I can do on my end. I suggested that they change the method to GET, as that seems to work, too.